# Azure load balanced servers fail to mount NFS share

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, azure, nfs

I have deployed an NFS server on an Azure Ubuntu 14.04LTS VM. My 2 NFS clients sit behind an Azure load balancer (also Ubuntu 14.04LTS).

When trying to mount the share with:

```
mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 {serverIP}:/nfs_share /mount_point
```

I get the following result:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting {IP}:{share}
```

If I run `showmount -e {server-IP}` from the LBS client it correctly lists the shares.

Mounting the NFS share from my Amazon servers works fine, so I don't seem to have a server config or firewall issue.

This seems to narrow it down to the Azure LBS clients, but I can't work out why. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, maybe we should check the NFS server /etc/exports configuration.
Here is my test (in the same VNet) and it work for me:
[image]
The 52.186.122.24 is the IP of the client behind an Azure load balancer (not the load balancer IP).
[image]
By the way, I had open the port 2049 in the NSG, we can test in our client use telnet IP with port 2049. 
Internal IP also works for NFS.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think you may have hit on the problem. While troubleshooting, I tried using an * in /etc/exports to allow connection from anywhere. And indeed it works from anywhere, except the instances behind the balancer. These instances don't have a public IP addresses - they use the Ip address of the load balancer + port assignment. I am coming to Azure from Amazon, and assigning a public IP is very straightforward there. I just tried to assign a public IP to the instances behind the load balancer, but can't work our where it's done in Azure.

Comment: Hi Lila,do you mean you have assign a public IP to the instances? so your NFS server and client all have public IPs, so we can use the public IP to mount the NFS. If we use public IP, we need to open the port 2049 in the NSG with azure portal,(NSG is network security groups, same as the firewall, the port is closed by default)